# Configure Nagios to read from SharePoint Online list

Tags: nagios, sharepoint, microsoft-office-365, centreon

I have a SharePoint Online list with domains and the dates on which they expire. I would like to be able to configure Nagios (Centreon 2.1.6) to read the expiry date of a domain from the list and alert me when a domain name is due to expire. I know many registrars offer reminder services but I'd like to be able to set up an alert which will email me 90 days, 60 days and then 30 days before a domain is due to expire.

EDIT: Whois sites cannot retrieve the expiration date of certain SLDs, such as .com.au or .de. Thus, I created this list so I can update the expiry date each time I renew a domain. It's the most accurate, up-to-date way I can think of to keep track of my domains. I just need to know how to get Nagios to retrieve the fields with the domain name and expiry date in it.

Are there any plugins out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

No matter how accurate your list might be (for now), the only way to **really** know the expiration date is the WHOIS record.

You want something like [check_whois.pl](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Internet-Domains-and-WHOIS/check_whois-2Epl-%28Advanced-Nagios-Plugins-Collection%29/details). (There are many `check_whois` variants out there.)

**Edit**: Sorry to answer the question you didn't-quite-ask, but reading a list of things to check out of a SharePoint list isn't really in scope for a Nagios plugin. You're essentially asking "is there a plugin that can read a list of dates from an arbitrary document location and tell me if any of them have passed?"

You'd have to write code to do this, assuming there's some API you can use to fetch the list. Otherwise, you'll have to do NTLM auth, I guess? There are certainly plugins for checking "SharePoint health", from which you could borrow login code, like [check_sharepoint_webpage.sh](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Websites,-Forms-and-Transactions/check_sharepoint_webpage-2Esh/details) or [check_sharepoint.pl](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/Microsoft-Sharepoint/check_sharepoint-2Epl/details)

Comment: Whois sites cannot retrieve the expiration date of certain SLDs, such as .com.au or .de. Thus why I have this list, so I can update the expiry date each time I renew a domain. It's the most accurate, up-to-date way I can think of to keep track of my domains. I just need to know how to get nagios to retrieve the fields with the domain name and expiry date in it.

Comment: You should update your question with this additional information.

Comment: Edited. And no, I asked if there was a plugin that can read a date field from a SharePoint list (not a document library) and send an alert 30, 60, and 90 days before that date.